# Rounding Numbers to 2 decimals doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I did everything to round numbers that appear in column D to 2 decimals but failed using VBA
why it appears rounded to 2 decimals but when I hover over and click on the cell it stays the same and it's not rounded in the formula bar?

N.B: I used a simple formula which is multiplying the amounts in column D in the currency rate then I copied the result and paste it again in the same cell using paste special

[image]

Comment: You will need to round the number itself and return the result.  copy paste always uses the actual value not the number format:  `ActiveSheet.Range("D3") = Application.Round(ActiveSheet.Range("D3"),2)`

Comment: "I did everything to round numbers that appear in column D to 2 decimals" - what did you actually do though?